# What is the time complexity of recursion approach (Java) for "Maximum Depth of Binary Tree"?

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity

This question is taken from "Maximum Depth of Binary Tree" of LeetCode:

```
Given a binary tree, find its maximum depth.

The maximum depth is the number of nodes along the longest path from the root node down to the farthest leaf node.
```

Well, the recursion approach is pretty simple:

```
public int maxDepth (TreeNode root) {  
    if(root == null)  
        return 0;  
    return Math.max(maxDepth(root.left),maxDepth(root.right))+1;  
}
```

I just cannot figure out the time complexity of this solution. Somebody says it's `O(n)`. Aren't `maxDepth(root.left)` and `maxDepth(root.right)` computed simultaneously, which would make the time complexity `O(lg(n))`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

maxDepth(root.left) and maxDepth(root.right) can be computed simultaneously only if you are running them in parallel, and if you are, you complexity depends on the number of available processors that can run in parallel. That said, your Java code is not running anything in parallel, since all of it runs on the same thread.

Assuming sequential execution, `maxDepth` has to traverse the entire tree, since it doesn't know if a certain path can lead to a max Depth until it reaches the leaf that ends that path. Therefore the time complexity is O(n).

Answer (score 4):

As per Java specification, the leftmost parameter to the function is entirely evaluated first, then the right one. They are not computed at the same time algorithmically, and they are not executed at the same time chronologically on different threads/cores.

Think of it this way: the algorithm will go through every node exactly once. This means the algorithm is `O(n)`.

---

If you're not convinced, you can arrive at the same conclusion in a less holistic way using the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) (here in Wikipedia's notation):

For a tree of size N, we do two calls, each on one half of the tree, plus our constant work for that node (checking for null and adding 1):

```
T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + 1
       ^-a     ^-b  ^-f(n)
```

The theorem has multiple cases, and says that Case 1 covers algorithms where `f(n)` is `O(n^c)` where `c < log_b(a)` as indicated above. Our `f(n)` is `O(n^0)` (constant) and `log_b(a) = log2(2) = 1`. The theorem then states that the runtime is:

```
T(n) = Θ(n^log_b(a))
```

which for us means

```
T(n) = Θ(n^1) = Θ(n)
```

This is the generalized but far longer approach to reaching the same answer.